# An AJAX autocomplete textfield in Drupal 7 doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

An AJAX autocomplete textfield in Drupal 7 works in Firefox, but doesn't work in IE and Chrome. The following error appears:

> ```
> An AJAX HTTP error occured. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows.
> Path: http://localhost/drupal/en/example/autocomplete
> StatusText: OK
> ResponseText: {"admin":"admin","alex":"alex","apple":"apple"}
> ```

```
function clubform_menu() { 
  $items['example/autocomplete'] = array(
    'page callback' => '_module_name_autocomplete',
    'access arguments' => array('access example autocomplete'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );   
  return $items; 
} 

function _module_name_autocomplete($string) {
$matches = array();
$return = db_query("SELECT name FROM users where lower(name) like '".$string."%' LIMIT 10");
  // add matches to $matches 
  foreach ($return as $row) {
    $matches[$row->name] = check_plain($row->name);
  }
  // return for JS
  drupal_json_output($matches);
}

...
        $form['editclub']['club_name'] = array( 
          '#title' => t(''), 
          '#type' => 'textfield', 
          '#description' => t(''), 
          '#autocomplete_path' => 'example/autocomplete',
          '#weight' =>15, 
          '#size' => 30, 
         );
...
```

The output in Firefox is the following:

[image]

Comment: I don't know but AJAX doesn't work at all in Chrome and IE. I tried AJAX Examples and got the same error=(

Comment: Works just fine for me in IE8 and Chrome v14.  Are you sure you are logged in and have the proper permissions on the other browsers?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. Very strange things are happening. If a turn off all my modules it works but if i keep more than one module on it gives the same error. I don't understand what's the relationship can bew between them

Comment: I would see if you can find a pattern to which modules cause a problem.  The code seems correct (assuming you have that form item in a function to display the form) and works on my somewhat basic D7 install, must be a localized issue

Comment: If i turn on two modules newly created with the simple form it refuses to work in Chrome. But if i turn on one of them it works. I tried it also in a new Drupal 7 installation.

Comment: I found out what causes AJAX error! When I turn on any module with utf8 incoding it causes the error, when i change the encoding to ANSI or to utf8 without BOM, everything works. This incoding problems happened only in Google chrome, in Firefox all encodings work well.

Comment: Very nice :) I would recommend posting that as an answer and marking it accepted when you can (in 24 hrs) to help others later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out what causes AJAX error! When I turn on any module with UTF-8 encoding, it causes the error; when I change the encoding to ANSI or to UTF-8 without BOM, everything works. This encoding problem happened only in Google Chrome; in Firefox all encodings work well.