# How can I return actual JSON using Drupal?

Tags: nodes, javascript

I'd like to implement a simple AJAX function locally that allows me to autocomplete node titles of already existing nodes as the user types. To that end, I need the ability to have an API that I can search on node titles. The problem is that when I output raw JSON, it comes surrounded by tags. So, no matter what I do, I keep getting...

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;"> {json here}</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried implementing a custom page template that only outputs content already, that produced the same results. Here is how I am currently doing this, in my module file...

```
<?php

/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu()
 */
function content_relation_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['api'] = array(
        'title' => 'Search',
        'page callback' => 'content_relation_get',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}

function content_relation_get($term = '') {
    drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'application/javascript; utf-8');
    $var = json_encode(
        db_query("SELECT nid,title FROM {node} WHERE title LIKE :title LIMIT 5", array(":title" => $term.'%'))->fetchAll()
    );
    echo $var;
    exit(0);
}
```

How can I return JUST raw JSON?

Comment: You want the `drupal_json_output` function. See [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13887/an-ajax-autocomplete-textfield-in-drupal-7-doesnt-work-in-chrome) or [there](http://timonweb.com/how-create-ajax-autocomplete-textfield-drupal-7) for working examples.

Comment: Can some one show an example for Drupal 7

Comment: This is a real life example for Drupal 8: https://github.com/npinos/drupal8-greenhouse. It includes controller and routing, and returns a node count in JSON,  exposed as an endpoint.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For Drupal 6, you can use [drupal_json](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_json/6)

```
function content_relation_get($term = '') {
    $result = db_query("SELECT nid,title FROM {node} WHERE title LIKE :title LIMIT 5", array(":title" => $term.'%'))->fetchAll()
    );
    drupal_json($result);
    exit;
}
```

For Drupal 7, change it to use [drupal_json_output](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_json_output/7)

```
function content_relation_get($term = '') {
    $result = db_query("SELECT nid,title FROM {node} WHERE title LIKE :title LIMIT 5", array(":title" => $term.'%'))->fetchAll()
    );
    drupal_json_output($result);
    drupal_exit();
}
```

It would also probably be safer to parse out the query to sanitize, error check, etc, instead of just trying to return the result.

Comment: Just a quick note: it's generally preferable to use drupal_exit() instead of exit() after printing JSON.

Comment: @geerlingguy  Good catch; didn't notice that.  For those who don't know the difference, calling drupal_exit() will invoke hook_exit(), teardown the session, etc.

Answer (score 5):

I saw that there was no answer provided for Drupal 8.

In order to process JSON in Drupal 8, use the following code:

```
  <?php
     use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
     // ...
     $options = _menu_get_options(menu_get_menus(), $available_menus, array('mlid' => 0));
     return new JsonResponse($options);
  ?>
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1665684)